# How to set desired layout to the elements in different classes in c++ qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I am working on a project in which I am supposed to make two buttons(These buttons are named as Power calculation and Power calculation 2 ). When the user clicks on the buttons, a sliding area opens up under the buttons.
I have written this code successfully, but my problem is the layout of these buttons and the sliding area bellow each button(The buttons are defined in separate classes. The button named as "Power calculation" is defined in "Section.cpp" and the button named as "Power calculation 2" is defined in "Section2.cpp").
My goal is to set the buttons in the same row (the button named as "power calculation" must be on the left side of the button named as "Powercalculation2" and both of them are supposed to be in the same row). I use QGridLayout to set the layouts to my elements, but I can't get results. I have also tried to use move() and setGeometry() , but I could not get what I want to do.
I would appreciate if someone could help me in this matter.

The picture below is what I get after running my program:

[image: The output]

But the result that I want to get is the picture below:

[image: My goal]

MY project ui file picture:

[image: mainwindow.ui]

Here is my code:

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

 class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
   Q_OBJECT

public:
 explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
 ~MainWindow();

private:
   Ui::MainWindow *ui;
 };

 #endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Section.h:

```
#ifndef SECTION_H
#define SECTION_H

#include <QFrame>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QParallelAnimationGroup>
#include <QScrollArea>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QParallelAnimationGroup>
#include <QScrollArea>
#include <QToolButton>
#include <QWidget>
#include "Section2.h"

class Section : public QWidget {
   Q_OBJECT
private:

   QGridLayout* mainLayout;
   QToolButton* toggleButton;
   QFrame* headerLine;
   QParallelAnimationGroup* toggleAnimation;
   QScrollArea* contentArea;
   int animationDuration;


public slots:

  void toggle(bool collapsed);


public:
   explicit Section(const QString & title = "", const int animationDuration = 100, QWidget* parent = 
0);

  void setContentLayout(QLayout & contentLayout);
};

 #endif // SECTION_H
```

Section2.h:

```
#ifndef SECTION2_H
#define SECTION2_H

#include <QFrame>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QParallelAnimationGroup>
#include <QScrollArea>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QParallelAnimationGroup>
#include <QScrollArea>
#include <QToolButton>
#include <QWidget>

class Section2 : public QWidget {
   Q_OBJECT
private:

  QGridLayout* mainLayout;
  QToolButton* toggleButton;
  QFrame* headerLine;
  QParallelAnimationGroup* toggleAnimation;
  QScrollArea* contentArea;
  int animationDuration;


 public slots:

      void toggle(bool collapsed);


public:
   explicit Section2(const QString & title = "", const int animationDuration = 100, QWidget* parent = 
0);


 void setContentLayout(QLayout & contentLayout);
};

 #endif // SECTION_H
```

main.cpp:

```
 #include "mainwindow.h"
 #include <QApplication>

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
 }
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
 #include "mainwindow.h"
 #include "ui_mainwindow.h"
 #include "Section.h"
 #include "Section2.h"
 #include <QLabel>
 #include <QPushButton>
 #include <QBoxLayout>
 #include <QLineEdit>
 #include <QGridLayout>
 #include <QComboBox>
 #include <QDebug>
 #include <QRegularExpressionValidator>
 #include <QValidator>


 MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
     QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
 {
   ui->setupUi(this);


Section *section = new Section("Section", 100, ui->centralWidget);
ui->centralWidget->layout()->addWidget(section);

Section2 *section2 = new Section2("Section2", 100, ui->centralWidget);
ui->centralWidget->layout()->addWidget(section2);

QVBoxLayout* anyLayout = new QVBoxLayout();

QLabel *lblV = new QLabel("insert voltage",section);
anyLayout->addWidget(lblV);


QLineEdit *lineV = new QLineEdit("",section);
anyLayout->addWidget(lineV);


QLabel *lblI = new QLabel("insert current",section);
anyLayout->addWidget(lblI);


QLineEdit *lineI = new QLineEdit("",section);
anyLayout->addWidget(lineI);



QPushButton *btn = new QPushButton("power: ",section);
anyLayout->addWidget(btn);

QLabel *lbl = new QLabel("",section);
lbl->setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow");
anyLayout->addWidget(lbl);




QVBoxLayout* anyLayout2 = new QVBoxLayout();

QLabel *lblV2 = new QLabel("insert voltage",section2);
anyLayout2->addWidget(lblV2);

QLineEdit *lineV2 = new QLineEdit("",section2);
anyLayout2->addWidget(lineV2);

QLabel *lblI2 = new QLabel("insert current",section2);
anyLayout2->addWidget(lblI2);

QLineEdit *lineI2 = new QLineEdit("",section2);
anyLayout2->addWidget(lineI2);



QPushButton *btn2 = new QPushButton("power: ",section2);
anyLayout2->addWidget(btn2);


QLabel *lbl2 = new QLabel("",section2);
lbl2->setStyleSheet("background-color: pink");
anyLayout2->addWidget(lbl2);

section->setContentLayout(*anyLayout);
section2->setContentLayout(*anyLayout2);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Section.cpp:

```
 #include <QPropertyAnimation>

 #include "Section.h"
 #include <QLabel>
 #include <QPushButton>
 #include <QLineEdit>

 Section::Section(const QString & title, const int animationDuration, QWidget* parent)
     : QWidget(parent), animationDuration(animationDuration)
 {
     toggleButton = new QToolButton(this);
     headerLine = new QFrame(this);
     toggleAnimation = new QParallelAnimationGroup(this);
      contentArea = new QScrollArea(this);
      mainLayout = new QGridLayout(this);

     toggleButton->setStyleSheet("QToolButton {border: none;}");
     toggleButton->setToolButtonStyle(Qt::ToolButtonTextBesideIcon);
     toggleButton->setArrowType(Qt::ArrowType::RightArrow);
     toggleButton->setText("Power calculation");
     toggleButton->setCheckable(true);
     toggleButton->setChecked(false);

     headerLine->setFrameShape(QFrame::HLine);
     headerLine->setFrameShadow(QFrame::Sunken);

     headerLine->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
     contentArea->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);


     // start out collapsed
     contentArea->setMaximumHeight(0);



    toggleAnimation->addAnimation(new QPropertyAnimation(contentArea, "maximumHeight"));

    mainLayout->setVerticalSpacing(0);



    mainLayout->addWidget(toggleButton, 0, 0, 1, 1);
    mainLayout->addWidget(headerLine, 0, 1, 1, 1);
    mainLayout->addWidget(contentArea, 3, 0, 1, 3);
    setLayout(mainLayout);




    connect(toggleButton, &QToolButton::toggled, this, &Section::toggle);



   }


 void Section::toggle(bool collapsed) {
    toggleButton->setArrowType(collapsed ? Qt::ArrowType::DownArrow : Qt::ArrowType::RightArrow);
    toggleAnimation->setDirection(collapsed ? QAbstractAnimation::Forward : 
    QAbstractAnimation::Backward);
    toggleAnimation->start();
  }




 void Section::setContentLayout(QLayout & contentLayout)
  {
    delete contentArea->layout();
    contentArea->setLayout(&contentLayout);


    const auto collapsedHeight = sizeHint().height() - contentArea->maximumHeight();
    auto contentHeight = contentLayout.sizeHint().height();


for (int i = 0; i < toggleAnimation->animationCount() - 1; ++i)

{
    QPropertyAnimation* SectionAnimation = static_cast<QPropertyAnimation *>(toggleAnimation->animationAt(i));
    SectionAnimation->setDuration(animationDuration);
    SectionAnimation->setStartValue(collapsedHeight);

    SectionAnimation->setEndValue(collapsedHeight + contentHeight);

 }

QPropertyAnimation* contentAnimation = static_cast<QPropertyAnimation *>(toggleAnimation->animationAt(toggleAnimation->animationCount() - 1));
contentAnimation->setDuration(animationDuration);
contentAnimation->setStartValue(0);
contentAnimation->setEndValue(contentHeight);

}
```

Section2.cpp:

```
#include <QPropertyAnimation>
#include "Section2.h"
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QLineEdit>

 Section2::Section2(const QString & title, const int animationDuration, QWidget* parent)
     : QWidget(parent), animationDuration(animationDuration)
  {
    toggleButton = new QToolButton(this);
    headerLine = new QFrame(this);
    toggleAnimation = new QParallelAnimationGroup(this);
    contentArea = new QScrollArea(this);
    mainLayout = new QGridLayout(this);

    toggleButton->setStyleSheet("QToolButton {border: none;}");
    toggleButton->setToolButtonStyle(Qt::ToolButtonTextBesideIcon);
    toggleButton->setArrowType(Qt::ArrowType::RightArrow);
    toggleButton->setText("Power calculation 2");
    toggleButton->setCheckable(true);
    toggleButton->setChecked(false);

    headerLine->setFrameShape(QFrame::HLine);
    headerLine->setFrameShadow(QFrame::Sunken);

   headerLine->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
   contentArea->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);


  // start out collapsed
   contentArea->setMaximumHeight(0);



   toggleAnimation->addAnimation(new QPropertyAnimation(contentArea, "maximumHeight"));

   mainLayout->setVerticalSpacing(0);


   mainLayout->addWidget(toggleButton, 0, 0, 1, 1);
   mainLayout->addWidget(headerLine, 0, 1, 1, 1);
   mainLayout->addWidget(contentArea, 3, 0, 1, 3);
   setLayout(mainLayout);


 connect(toggleButton, &QToolButton::toggled, this, &Section2::toggle);
}


 void Section2::toggle(bool collapsed) {
    toggleButton->setArrowType(collapsed ? Qt::ArrowType::DownArrow : Qt::ArrowType::RightArrow);
    toggleAnimation->setDirection(collapsed ? QAbstractAnimation::Forward : 
    QAbstractAnimation::Backward);
    toggleAnimation->start();
 }




 void Section2::setContentLayout(QLayout & contentLayout)
  {
    delete contentArea->layout();
    contentArea->setLayout(&contentLayout);


   const auto collapsedHeight = sizeHint().height() - contentArea->maximumHeight();
   auto contentHeight = contentLayout.sizeHint().height();


   for (int i = 0; i < toggleAnimation->animationCount() - 1; ++i)

    {
        QPropertyAnimation* SectionAnimation = static_cast<QPropertyAnimation *>(toggleAnimation- 
     >animationAt(i));
       SectionAnimation->setDuration(animationDuration);
       SectionAnimation->setStartValue(collapsedHeight);

       SectionAnimation->setEndValue(collapsedHeight + contentHeight);

    }

QPropertyAnimation* contentAnimation = static_cast<QPropertyAnimation *>(toggleAnimation- 
>animationAt(toggleAnimation->animationCount() - 1));
contentAnimation->setDuration(animationDuration);
contentAnimation->setStartValue(0);
contentAnimation->setEndValue(contentHeight);
   }
```

Comment: I usually do complex layouts in designer with mainly a combination of vertical and horizontal layouts and also expanders. If the forms have a repeated section where the same UI elements appear in multiple places and I want them to have the same layout I put them in their own widget and insert that widget multiple times in the main form to avoid repeated code.

Comment: Your question would probably be helped by a picture of the screen and if possible some work minimizing the amount of code.

Comment: It's hard to tell without picture, but it looks like you only define GridLayouts inside Section* classes with the individual buttons, while your main widget only has VBox layouts. If I didn't miss anything, you never put widgets containing the buttons into the GridLayout. Is this correct?

Comment: @drescherjm Thank you for replying. I updated my post and put both the output and my goal(what I want to get) pictures into my post. I would appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: @DanM. Thank you for replying. I updated my post and put both the output and my goal(what I want to get) pictures into my post. I would appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: @Nanor you say that you "I use QGridLayout to set the layouts to my elements, but I can't get results", but I don't see you using the GridLayout for your main widget anywhere. You don't seem to use any layout for your `section` and `section2` on centralWidget. What if you change ui->centralWidget layout to HBox/Grid before you add sections to it? I'm pretty sure that that's the crux of your problem, but not sure enough to make it an answer.

Comment: @DanM. Actually my mainwindow.ui has only vertical layout alignment for the centeralwidget. I define section and section 2 objects in mainwindow.cpp and set them into centeralwidget. Then I add labels and lineedits into section and section 2. So far, I make my contents in slider area. Then, in section.cpp and section2.cpp I define buttons and scrollarea and set them in my window by using gridlayout.

Comment: @Nanor "mainwindow has only vertical layout alignment for the centeralwidget. I define section and section 2 objects in mainwindow.cpp and set them into centeralwidget" <- that's why your section and section2 widgets are aligned vertically in your main window. The stuff you do in section.cpp and section2.cpp only controll the layout of items inside those two widgets, while, judging by your images, you want to change the layout of section* widgets themselves, so you need to act on centralWidget. Sounds logical? The layout only applies for its widget contents. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html

Comment: @DanM. I changed the layout vertically to horizontally and I got closer to what I am supposed to do. Now I understand the problem is with the layouts I set to the central widget (as you mentioned). Thank you so much! It was really helpful.

Comment: @Nanor good. I tried to create an answer out of this discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 widgets (`Section` and `Section2`) that contain other widgets (buttons/labels) that you want to be placed horizontally in your main window (inside `centralWidget`).

For that you need to set the appropriate layout to the `centralWidget` and add Section* items to that layout.

Right now, you just use the default layout of the `centralWidget`:

```
Section *section = new Section("Section", 100, ui->centralWidget);
ui->centralWidget->layout()->addWidget(section);

Section2 *section2 = new Section2("Section2", 100, ui->centralWidget);
ui->centralWidget->layout()->addWidget(section2);
```

> I use QGridLayout to set the layouts to my elements, but I can't get results.

This is because in your code you use QGridLayout to lay out the widgets inside each instance of `Section` and `Section2`.

```
mainLayout->addWidget(toggleButton, 0, 0, 1, 1);
mainLayout->addWidget(headerLine, 0, 1, 1, 1);
mainLayout->addWidget(contentArea, 3, 0, 1, 3);
setLayout(mainLayout);
```

This controls how `toggleButton`, `headerLine` and `contentArea` are laid out inside Section* widgets, but has no effect on how Section widgets itself are positioned with respect to each other in some "higher level" widget (`centralWidget` in this case).

When you create your Section* widgets you can think of them as any other standard widget (button/label/etc.) and handle them accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for complete explanation. What about using QGridLayout  for laying out the section widgets? As you said, I can think of section widgets as any other standard widgets. I broke the central widget layout and tried to set Gridlayout to the section widgets (I set the section to the row=0 and the section2 to the row=1), but I did not successful to have these sections horizontally.

Comment: `Section *section = new Section("Section", 100,ui->centralWidget);
    mainLayoutS = new QGridLayout(ui->centralWidget);
    section->setLayout(mainLayoutS);
    mainLayoutS->addWidget(section, 0, 0, 1, 1);
    setLayout(mainLayoutS);`

Comment: `Section2 *section2 = new Section2("Section2", 100,ui->centralWidget);
    mainLayoutS = new QGridLayout(ui->centralWidget);
    section2->setLayout(mainLayoutS);
    mainLayoutS->addWidget(section2, 0, 1, 1, 1);
    setLayout(mainLayoutS);`

Comment: The previous comments are the codes I used to lay out the sections after breaking the centralwidget layout .

Comment: @Nanor Why having one widgets in ro 1 and another in ro 2 would place them horizontally? Do you know what row is? Rows are horizontal. Columns are vertical. You want your items in the same row, but in different columns. Also, try HBox layout if you'd only have one row.

Comment: The reason I put them in different rows is that I broke the central widget layout(so it is not horizontal anymore). I wanted to have different buttons in different rows and columns and tried to work with gridlayout.

Comment: Because in the next stage, I am supposed to have multiple buttons in different rows and columns.

Comment: I figured out what was missed in my code. I set two sections in central widget which its layout was broken, but I forgot to set layout to it, when I layed out the sections with QGridlayout!! Now my code works fine! Really appreciate your help. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Nanor Great! Please mark answer as accepted, if it helped you!

Comment: @Dan.M Sure.Done!